# SharePoint Discussion Lists E-mail

Tags: list, email

I’ve been using email enabled discussion boards lately, but I’ve found them to be far less than ideal. Are e-mail enabled discussion lists are really this finicky, or have I configured something wrong?

1.)
**You cannot change the subject. All replies must match the subject of the discussion and include Re:**. ***(This is reasonable, and far less concerning than #2)***

**Discussion board subject**

*“My Subject Name”*

**Discussion board e-mail reply:**

*“Re: My Subject Name”*

2.)
**The replying email must include the original discussion body.**

*“This is my response”*

**On Jan 9, 2018, at 9:15 PM, MyName  wrote:**

*This is the discussion I am replying to*

**I have read that SharePoint decides that an e-mail is a response by checking the body of the message for the reply separator (-------).**